# How to loop through a number by step but no exceed the number in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and I am attempting to create an array of numbers with a maximum and minumum value and step.I figured this would be straight forward. But I am not getting the desired array :

Here is my current code :

```
let list = []
let max = 27
let min = 10
let step = 10
for (let i = min; i <= max; i += step) {
  list.push(i);
}
```

This gives me an array of `[10, 20, 30]`

But I would like the last number in the array to be the max number. So the expected result would be an array of `[10, 20, 27]`

How would I achieve that? Thanks

Comment: This gave `[ 1, 11, 21 ]`..

Comment: Oh sorry I mean a minimum of 10

Comment: What's the point of `step`?

Comment: Just edited my code. My apologies. Did it in a rush. The step is 10.

Comment: You could use `i < max` and manually push `max` after the loop via `list.push(max)` (with `i <= max`, you could end up with the two last entries being equal to `max`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you don't actually specify a limit on what goes into the array, only the limit of `i` at which point you want the loop to stop evaluating-- amd you are always pushing in the index (`i`) regardless of the `max`.

```js
let list = []
let max = 27
let min = 10
let step = 10
for (let i = min; i <= max; i += step) {
  list.push(i);
}

console.log(list);
```

This actually yields `[10, 20]`; because after you push `20` in the next value of `i` is `30`, which is lower than the `max`, so the loop exits.

If you want the `max` to be the highest value in the array but it doesn't divide evenly by your step size, you'll need to do some additional checks:

```js
function fillArray(min, max, step) {
  const list = [];
  for (let i = min; i <= max; i += step) {
    list.push(i);
  }
  if (max % step !== 0) {
    list.push(max);
  }
  return list;
}

console.log(fillArray(10, 27, 10));

console.log(fillArray(0, 30, 5));
```

**OR**, as user [@sp00m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1225328/sp00m) correctly points out, this can be improved to omit the `if` condition by changing the `for` condition:

```js
function fillArray(min, max, step) {
  const list = [];
  for (let i = min; i < max; i += step) {
    list.push(i);
  }
  list.push(max);
  return list;
}

console.log(fillArray(10, 27, 10));

console.log(fillArray(0, 30, 5));
```

This doesn't handle all edge cases-- you could probably make it more robust.

Comment: You could use `i < max` and always push `max` once done looping.

Comment: @sp00m - great call out-- I've updated the response, thanks!

Comment: Thanks! This was really helpful

Answer (score 1):

### Try this using `do ..while` loop

```js
let list = []
let i = 0
let max = 27
let min = 1
let step = 10

do {
  i++
  var item = i * step
  if (item >= max) item = max
  list.push(item);
} while (list[i - 1] < max)

console.log(list)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have `if (item >= max) item = max` rather than hardcoding it to 27?  Otherwise it fails for any other `max` value...

Comment: Oh.. Sorry!  missed that.., thanks!! for such a nice attention! . updated the answer.